# Difference between system app and 3rd party apps?

Tags: applications, system-apps, optimization

I was reading about best system optimisation app for android, and this thought came into my mind as what's the difference if you optimise  through a 3rd party app or the system app.

So let's say I am using X app (3rd Part) and I clean the space other app are using. It shows me how much memory it was using and shows me available space that I get after performing that action.

Now if use the android system app to the same action, it  shows some that there was some space that was realised hence allowing me to optimise . If both do the same whats the difference ?? In using 3rd party app and System app. !!!

Confused

Comment: It's hard to read and understand your question, but I guess you ask why the system app will clean more space? Well, a system app has more permissions (inherited from the system) and thus sees more used space and what it is used for; a normal app does not have the permission to do that (basic principle of app separation and user protection).

Answer (score 0):

Both do the same job but you can more rely on system app rather than 3rd party app.Because all they have the permissions to do so more efficiently.If your device is rooted then all the permissions you can set to the app as your requirements.